# insert formatted page numbers in MS Word

Tags: ms-word

Okay.. I kinda feel stupid asking this question. But since i haven't found an answer to it yet, this is my only hope.

I have a MS Word 2010 document of 30 pages. I need to add page numbers to it in the following format.

```
1st page: Cover page  - no page number
2nd page: declaration - page i
3rd page: acknowledgement - page ii
4th page: index - page iii
5th page: summary - page 1
6th page: introduction - page 2
..... and so on till last page conclusion - page 26
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: If I recall correctly, look at section breaks

Comment: @IanKenney yes.. i think section breaks might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Format Page Numbering**

To format the page numbering for different sections, follow these **steps**:

1. Click between two parts of your document that you want to number
   differently.
2. On the Insert menu, click **Break**.
3. Click Next Page, Even Page, or Odd Page, and then click OK.
4. For Help on an option, click the question mark, and then click the
   option.
5. Click in the first section.
6. On the View menu, click Header and Footer.
7. Click in the header or footer where you want the page number.
8. On the Header and Footer toolbar, click Insert Page Number.
9. On the Header and Footer toolbar, click Format Page Number.
10. In the Number format box, click the format that you want for the
     numbers in this section.
11. Do one of the following:
12. If you want the page numbering for the first page in this section to
    start at a particular number other than the first number in the
    format series, click Start at under Page numbering, and then enter
    the first number that you want to appear on the first page of the
    section.
13. If you want the page numbering to continue from the previous
    section, click Continue from previous section.
14. Click OK.
15. On the Header and Footer toolbar, click Show Next.
16. Repeat steps 8 through 11 for the page numbering in this section.
17. On the Header and Footer toolbar, click Close.

[Source:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326536)

Comment: is there a way to link them all together in one document? like if i have to send this whole document to someone, and i create 3 separate documents, how should i send it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert Section Breaks between the various sections you have outlined. Each section can be numbered differently using the Headers and Footers view.

Comment: guide here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-steps-to-setting-up-page-numbering-in-word-sections/1827